# How to find the WiFi password on XP?

Tags: wifi, windows-xp, password-recovery

This is not as simple as it may seem.  I've got 2 hosts connected via wifi and I need to know the password they use. I cannot access the access point cause I don't know the credentials. When i get in the network property panel from XP I can't find the authentication tab anywhere. I also tried to install some software to find it. That almost worked. It gave me an hex code and not the proper password. I tried to convert that code to ascii but the resulting string was not correct. Finally I decided to contact the company whose name was on the router. I did that more times and every time they gave me different pass codes but none of them worked. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try the programs on nirsoft.net

Comment: but be careful, this question is off topic ;-)

Answer (score -1):

here is a best way to find wifi password http://www.info9.pw/